# TEFCA: Do providers have to give individuals fast electronic access to their health data?

Tags: united-states, medical, data-ownership, hipaa

TEFCA creates a network of providers who service health information requests.

The Sequoia Project's documentation on [required flow-down provisions](https://rce.sequoiaproject.org/summary-of-required-flow-down-provisions/) asserts:

- "Participants and Subparticipants may elect to offer IAS, but are not required to do so."
- "QHINs must support all Exchange Purposes. Participants and Subparticipants are permitted to Respond to all Exchange Purposes but are only required to Respond to those designated as “required” in the Exchange Purposes SOP. The initial required Exchange Purposes will be Treatment and Individual Access Services (IAS)."
- [on IAS providers] "Individuals also have the right to an export of their Individually Identifiable information in a computable format, including the means to interpret such information as set forth in Section 10.4."

These statements seem to imply contradicting stances on access to health data:

- *[stance 1]* A QHIN must service IAS requests. A Participant or Subparticipant must Respond to IAS requests. Individuals that an IAS provider services must actually receive the data.
- *[stance 2]* A QHIN must service IAS requests. A Participant/Subparticipant may decide if it participates in IAS. If it says no, it has no obligations at all.

I wrote the Health Gorilla QHIN to ask about this. Their sales representative said:

> While IAS is technically active via Qualified Health Information Networks, unfortunately, the vast majority of the healthcare ecosystem is not responding to an individual's request for their records. For example, no Epic user responds to an individual's request for their records.

This seems troubling. If all of an individual's providers do not elect to offer IAS, then the individual may have a paper right to their data without any actual access.

These are the questions I'm left with:

- Are QHINs obligated to service IAS requests?
- What are networks, Participants, and Subparticipants required to do?
- Does TEFCA create a faster process to get electronic health data than the HIPAA process?